# How I add image in powerpoint with OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

How I add image in powerpoint with OpenXML C#?

Anyone have an example of how to insert image in a certain position and size?
And how to edit a text box to position and size?

Here is what I have so far:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:/img.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))             
{
     var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
     ImagePart imagePart = slidePart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, "rId3");
     imagePart.FeedData(stream);   
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I try 
`using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:/img.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                ImagePart imagePart = slidePart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, "rId3");
                imagePart.FeedData(stream);
           }`

But not working

Comment: @MrD you added the image to the package already, now you need to take that imageId and use that to access it in your slides

Comment: @AlexanderDerck how I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Use below Code:

```
public static void AddImage(string file, string image)
    {
        using (var presentation = PresentationDocument.Open(file, true))
        {
            var slidePart = presentation
                .PresentationPart
                .SlideParts
                .First();

            var part = slidePart
                .AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(image))
            {
                part.FeedData(stream);
            }

            var tree = slidePart
                .Slide
                .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeTree>()
                .First();

            var picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture();

            picture.NonVisualPictureProperties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualPictureProperties();
            picture.NonVisualPictureProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualDrawingProperties
            {
                Name = "My Shape",
                Id = (UInt32)tree.ChildElements.Count - 1
            });

            var nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
            nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks()
            {
                NoChangeAspect = true
            });
            picture.NonVisualPictureProperties.Append(nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties);
            picture.NonVisualPictureProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties());

            var blipFill = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.BlipFill();
            var blip1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip()
            {
                Embed = slidePart.GetIdOfPart(part)
            };
            var blipExtensionList1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipExtensionList();
            var blipExtension1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipExtension()
            {
                Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
            };
            var useLocalDpi1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Drawing.UseLocalDpi()
            {
                Val = false
            };
            useLocalDpi1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main");
            blipExtension1.Append(useLocalDpi1);
            blipExtensionList1.Append(blipExtension1);
            blip1.Append(blipExtensionList1);
            var stretch = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch();
            stretch.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.FillRectangle());
            blipFill.Append(blip1);
            blipFill.Append(stretch);
            picture.Append(blipFill);

            picture.ShapeProperties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeProperties();
            picture.ShapeProperties.Transform2D = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D();
            picture.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
            });
            picture.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents
            {
                Cx = 1000000,
                Cy = 1000000,
            });
            picture.ShapeProperties.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry
            {
                Preset = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle
            });

            tree.Append(picture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi @Md. Zakir i am using the above code (thank you by the way) i am having dificulty in where the iamge is placed no matter what i seem to do it is placed in the top left hand corner.

Comment: Hi, to fit image in a specific position you have to control it. picture.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
            }); Here you have to place position value in X & Y

Comment: @md-zakir-hossain thank you that pointed me in the right direction i was also confused by the actual scales its using something like marco pixels (can't remeber the correct name) but x had to be something like 340,500 aand similar for y was massive numbers.. but this helped..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool to decompile a powerpoint file to c#.Create a file with Image and TextBox, decompile and see how it's done in c#.

Comment: That's super cool, thank you! Presently, seems to be hosted here on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5